# Parsing - Why C++ has trouble with template var decls and java doesn't with generic var decls?

Tags: java, c++, parsing, syntax, compiler-construction

In C++, if I write `a < b > c`, the meaning can either be an expression statement `(a < b) > c` or a declaration of variable c of type `a<b>`.

How come this is not a problem in java? Was the `(a < b) > c` option obsoleted by generics because although it parses, it always ends up as a type error? Did C++ insist on leaving this option for backward compatibility?

Comment: The meaning _can be_ either of those, but what's the concrete problem? It works fine if the compiler can tell `a` is a template

Comment: Even if it compiled, `a < b > c` won't work the way it looks.

Comment: @RustyX - To me it looks like someone wants to compare c against 1 if a is less than b and against 0 if it isn't ;)

Comment: Because Java doesn't have template var decls.

Comment: @EJP - `List<Integer> you_are_wrong;`

Comment: @tohava Java doesn't have templates either. It has a similar syntax, but for Generics, which is something quite different.

Comment: You are talking about the semantic meaning, which doesn't interest me for this discussion. I am interested in this purely from the angle of building a parser.

Comment: You are talking about something which doesn't exist in Java. If you're going to be a compiler writer you need to start by using the correct terminology.

Comment: @EJP - Edited the title to reflect the question better

Comment: @SamiHult - Ok, and is there any reasonable reason why someone would write that in C++? If not, why was it not obsoleted?

Comment: I'll gather this up to an answer.

Comment: Java doesn't allow arbitrary expressions to be statements, and `a<b...` is unambiguously a local declaration. Or is that not what you wanted to know? I'm  not sure how to interpret "is/is not a problem".

Comment: According to http://proiot.ru/jsjavaparser/ , java allows expressions as statements. For example, you can have `a > b < c;’ as a statement. @rici

Comment: @tohava: silly me. I was going by the [official Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8). Obviously, some random online hackery is more authoritative.

Comment: Ok, I am convinced, thank you. @nci

Comment: If you make this into an answer I will upvote and accept. @nci

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really a problem for either C++ or Java, for different reasons.

In Java, `a < b > c;` can only be a declaration because arbitrary expressions cannot be [expression statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8). The list of possible expression statements does not include comparison or arithmetic expressions (other than pre/post increment/decrement), so the statement must be a local declaration, and in that context `a` must be a generic type.

In C++, a `<` can only be a template bracket if it follows an identifier which has been declared as a template, and that declaration needs to precede the use of the identifier. Although that's not particularly clean design (it requires a context-sensitive parser), that issue was already present in C, which cannot be correctly parsed without knowing whether an identifier is a type alias or not. [Note 1] That basically requires giving the lexical scanner access to the symbol table, and ensuring that the symbol table at least includes accurate information about the "kind" (though not the type/class) of every identifier.

---

#### Notes

1. As Ira Baxter points out, an alternative to context-sensitive parsing is to perform a context-free parse using a GLR (or equivalent) parsing engine, which retains all possible parses. The ambiguity can then be resolved with semantic analysis following the parse. This is certainly an acceptable strategy, but I don't believe it was the one contemplated by the language designers, who assumed that it was important to declare types and templates before their use.

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle difference between truthy and falsy values in the two languages.

In Java `(a < b) > c` would be a comparison between boolean value and c, and that doesn't make much sense even if c was a boolean too. Since Java does not have operator overloading, there cannot be a situation where `(a < b) > c` could not be written as `(a < b) != c`.

In C++ on the other hand, operator overloading allows you to assign a completely different semantics to `<` or `>`. Thus, `a < b` might not be boolean at all.

Comment: Still doesnt explain why cpp did not bsolete a < b > c. If no beter answer will appear I will accept. i just upvoted anyway.